# Existence of p=-infinity norm

Tags: norms

Given a vector $\mathbf {x} =(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n})$ the p-norm is defined as 
$$
\left\|\mathbf {x} \right\|_{p}:={\bigg (}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left|x_{i}\right|^{p}{\bigg )}^{1/p}
$$
for $p \geq 1$.

For $p=\infty$ one obtains the maximum norm
$$\left\|\mathbf {x} \right\|_{\infty }:=\max \left(\left|x_{1}\right|,\ldots ,\left|x_{n}\right|\right). $$

I was wondering what happens if we consider the case $p=-\infty$?

From some numerical experiments it seems like
$$
\lim_{p\rightarrow -\infty}  \bigg (\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left|x_{i}\right|^{p}{\bigg )}^{1/p}= \min \left(\left|x_{1}\right|,\ldots ,\left|x_{n}\right|\right).
$$
Does this result hold in general? I could not find any reference for this problem.

Comment: It's not a norm, though.

Comment: The other interesting limit case is $p=0$.  That is, $$\lim_{p\to 0}\left(\frac{|x_1|^p+\dots+|x_n|^p}{n}\right)^{1/p}$$The geometric mean

Comment: I think this question is well suited for math.SE ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this limit is correct (subject to Yemon Choi's comment). See for example the section on means, in the book *Analytic Inequalities* by Mitrinovic.

Answer (score 4):

A simple relation between $\|\cdot\|_p$ and $\|\cdot\|_{-p}$ is
$$
\displaystyle\left\|\frac{1}{\mathbf x}\right\|_{-p} = \frac{1}{\|\mathbf x\|_{p}}
$$
where $\frac{1}{\mathbf x}$ is defined with components $\frac{1}{x_k}$.  You then easily deduce your min formula from the max formula you already stated.  Of course, all $x_n$ are nonzero, so that you can do negative powers.